# When typing in editable ComboBox not showing DropDown list

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm working with `ComboBox` in WPF. `ComboBox` IsEditable property setted to True`IsEditable="True"`. `ComboBox` has several items. When I'm typing it is showing item in `ComboBox` text, but not showing DropDown list. 
**XAML code:**

```
 <ComboBox Name="uiComboBox" IsEditable="True">
        <ComboBoxItem>One1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>One2</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>One3</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>One4</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Two</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Three</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

When I typing  "o" showing first item that starts with "o", in this case it is "One1"
[image]

When I  type "o" it should show me DropDown list with items that starts with "o" in this case 4 items, you can see in picture in below.[image]

After researching I found:

```
 private void ComboBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        uiComboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
    }
```

It is showing all not items that starts with letter i typed.
Any ideas to do that or maybe another control to use for this case?

Comment: take a look on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001842/dynamic-filter-of-wpf-combobox-based-on-text-input

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard the term called "Roll your own"? That's what you will need to do or I am sure some one out there wants the same thing and there should be tons of information about this on the web.

Take a look at these:

[Filter ComboBox items based on TextBox text](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/edb7d2a0-98f1-409d-acfc-e147342f6c89/filter-combobox-items-based-on-textbox-text)

[Dynamic filter of WPF combobox based on text input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001842/dynamic-filter-of-wpf-combobox-based-on-text-input)

I hope that helps!