# Why do I need to set IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem for certain ComboBox ItemsSource binding sources?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox, itemssource

I have a WPF control inheriting from ComboBox whose `ItemsSource` is bound to a list of elements, and whose `SelectedItem` is bound to another field. I have two references to the same list in my application: one resides in my `MainWindow` class, and one resides in my `App` class.

The list of elements used as the `ItemsSource` is assigned to the `ComboBox` at the time it is created. Thus, I expect to get an `ItemsSourceChanged` event.

The strange thing is, if the `ItemsSource` is bound to the `MainWindow`'s list, then the `ComboBox` becomes populated with the correct `SelectedItem` drawn from the bound field. However, if I bind the `ItemsSource` to the App's copy of the list, then the `SelectedItem` becomes overwritten with null due to the `ItemsSourceChanged` event.

Here is the XAML for the `ComboBox` when it's binding to the `App` copy of the list:

```
<local:TagSelectionComboBox FilteredTagsList="{Binding Path=TagsList, Source={x:Static Application.Current}}" SelectedItem="{Binding TagValue}"></local:TagSelectionComboBox>
```

Here is the XAML for the `ComboBox` when it's binding to the `MainWindow` copy of the list:

```
<local:TagSelectionComboBox FilteredTagsList="{Binding TagsList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" SelectedItem="{Binding TagValue}"></local:TagSelectionComboBox>
```

Here is the `MainWindow`'s property used for binding:

```
public ObservableCollection<Tag> TagsList
{
    get { return proj.Sim.Tags; }
}
```

And here is the `App`'s property used for binding:

```
public ObservableCollection<Tag> TagsList
{
    get { return proj.Sim.Tags; }
}
```

So these two properties on `App` and `MainWindow` are returning the same list. Stepping through in the debugger confirms: `proj.Sim.Tags` contains the same list in both cases.

**Why does changing from one binding source to another alter the binding behavior? Is something else going on?**

I've found that if I explicitly set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"`, then the behavior is the same in both cases. So it's almost like `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` is the default behavior when I use the `MainWindow` (`RelativeSource`) binding but `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"` is the default behavior when I use the `App` (`x:Static`) binding.

Background: the ComboBox-derived control in this question is basically the same as YantingChen's answer for this question:

[Dynamic filter of WPF combobox based on text input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001842/dynamic-filter-of-wpf-combobox-based-on-text-input)

Comment: The SelectedItem must refer to an item that must be contained in the ItemsSource (same instance).

Comment: IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem is only relevant when you want to synchronize the current collection view with the SelectedItem of the collection source. Otherwise the view won't track the selected items.